# Can we create a Single page application in Okta using OpenId connect sign on without having authorization server?

Tags: authorization, okta

I am working on a prototype where we need to integrate Okta in our angular application. The standard documentation of OKta for angular requires authorization server to present in the okta org. However, My organisation Okta doesn't have API management license and therefore we do not have any Authorization server tab.
Now how can I enable the authentication in my angular app by using Openid connect without authorization server?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: An authorization server is required for OIDC.

Comment: Hi @MattRaible. Thanks for the info. However, I have a question that if I have a Single Page Application built using Angular and Asp.net WebAPI, can we use SAML in that case? If not than why?